# Short key for moving windows between monitors?

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, window, cinnamon

Is there a short key to move a window between the different connected monitors?

In my setup I have 2 monitors in use. Usually I am on Unity, but I also use Cinnamon. Is there a way to move a window from say the left monitor to the right monitor?

Comment: @RoVo Actually, your first suggested link seems to only focus on one monitor. The second link you provided though using compiz may be a possible solution.

Comment: Yes, I tried the compiz solution myself and it works. If I retract my first vote, I cannot add another one. ;-)

Comment: @RoVo Then post an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: no, your question is a duplicate and should be closed as such

Comment: @karel That's the second link that RoVo already has posted above.

Comment: @Socrates I knew that when I posted it but it was posted automatically by the website when I reviewed it in order for the other reviewers to see the little gray number beside it which indicates how many other reviewers accepted the same link.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left/Right</kbd>.

Comment: doesn't work for me (16.04)

Comment: I work on 18/04 but you can try change it in Keyboards => Navigation => Move window one monitor to the left and Move window one monitor to the right

Comment: yes sure it might work on 18.04, but the question is about unity

Comment: can you try above approach

Comment: unity != gnome, no there is no such option in unity.

Comment: sorry man, I was using [alt] + [F7] to move the window